# TypeError: Network request failed On Android React native with server url , ios OK

Tags: android, reactjs, native

As call API with fetch/Axios, it gives the error Network request failed,i t is only occurred in Android devices ios working fine.
And also my server URL has dash like "https://stg-example.com"

Answer (score 0):

I’m also getting this error when build android